# JR Norris, Markov Chains, Exercise 1.1.1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, proof-writing

I'm reading JR Norris' book on Markov Chains, and to get the most out of it, I want to do the exercises. However, I'm falling at the first fence; I can't think of a convincing way to answer his first question! I'm a bit rusty with my mathematical rigor, and I think that is exactly what is needed here.

Exercise 1.1.1 splits into two parts. The first gives you a countably infinite series of sets that partition the event space, $\{B_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$. Then the question gives you another set, A, which obeys, $\mathbb{P}[A|B_{i}]=p, \forall i$. You have to show that $\mathbb{P}[A]=p$.

I initially thought that there should be a nifty way of using the addition rule here. And I think that you can use it to get at the answer, but the approach I ended up with was not in any way elegant. I've tried to write it out below: $$\mathbb{P}[A \cap B_{i}]=\mathbb{P}[A|B_{i}].\mathbb{P}[B_{i}]$$
$$\Rightarrow \mathbb{P}[A \cap B_{i}]=p.\mathbb{P}[B_{i}]$$So, summing over i on RHS, $$\sum_{i} p.\mathbb{P}[B_{i}]=p\sum_{i}\mathbb{P}[B_{i}]=p.$$
Summing over i on LHS is trickier, and is the point where the addition rule comes into play:$$\sum_{i}\mathbb{P}[A\cap B_{i}]=\mathbb{P}\left[\bigcup_{i}(A\cap B_{i})\right],$$ which follows directly from the probability addition rule*.
Continuing with the LHS: $$\mathbb{P}\left[\bigcup_{i}(A\cap B_{i})\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[A\cap\left(\bigcup_{i}B_{i}\right)\right], $$ by associativity of set operators. Finally, $$LHS=\mathbb{P}[A],$$ which is a property of the partition.

The problem with this is that it's very 'handwavy', particularly at the point *. How can I tighten it up?

Additionally, I think you can visualise the sets and probabilities described in the exercise by thinking of the state space as a big circle, divided up into $B_{i}s$ by radii, and the subset A being inscribed as a smaller circle. I can't think, though, how this intuitive way of viewing the situation can be turned into something rigorous. Any ideas?

<del>[The second part of the exercise asks you to show the equivalence of two statements dealing with conditional probabilities and their definition. Again I think the emphasis is on rigor. I may add it here at a later point but I don't have it to hand at the moment.]</del>

In the second part of the exercise, two random variables are considered: X & Y. The exercise asks us to show the equivalence of:

> (a) X & Y are independent; and
>   (b) The conditional distribution of X given Y = y is independent of y.

How do I show this, bearing in mind the result from the first part of the exercise?

Many thanks, and apologies for the long windedness,
Phillip

PS You can find the original exercise here, on page 7.

Comment: The last line of my proof should say $LHS=\matbb{P}[A].

Comment: you can edit your posts yourself, but I took the liberty of adding that missing $\mathbb{P}[A]$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is perfectly correct and you essentially prove the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability) along the way. The * part you are worried about follows from the fact the $B_{i}$ are disjoint, since they partition the space, so you can simply apply [the third probability axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom).

I personally find it difficult to visualise this problem geometrically since the $B_{i}$'s are countable family and so we are dealing with sums as opposed to integrals.

Comment: Actually it is not that hard to visualize through Venn's diagram, if you really need that. Just draw a big rectangle, representing the whole sample space. Then partition it into many pieces like a puzzle, representing $B_i$ for each piece. Finally on top of that draw a circle, representing $A$. That is all you need.